# Python: How to call a class in the same file

Tags: python

How do I call a function from a class, inside another, within the same file. 
My file looks like this:

```
class one:
    def get(self):
        return 1

class two:
    def init(self):
        get class one get()
```

I am trying to access the get function of class one, inside class two.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that you need to have classes here? Or would a simple function be enough?

Comment: yes i needed it to prevent function mix up, as well as easier to remember.

Comment: What do you mean "prevent function mix up"? I don't think you really understand what classes are **for** given your description.

Comment: well classes is important for me since they will act as "categories". For example class games will have games only, and class moderation will have mod tools only. I can't mix mod tools in games class since it will confuse myself out

Comment: easier explanation is if I don't want use multiple classes it will be like merging regex function under class urllib.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `One.get()` directly if you turn it into a static method:

```
class One:
    @staticmethod
    def get():
        return 1

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        val = One.get()
```

Without the `@staticmethod`, you need an instance of `One` in order to be able to call `get()`:

```
class One:
    def get(self):
        return 1

class Two:
    def __init__(self):
        one = One()
        val = one.get()
```

Answer (score 3):

NPE's answer is correct one. Also, if you want to call class by name (string value), you can use next solution:

```
class_name_type = globals()['class_name']
class_object = class_name_type()
```

Comment: or just `obj = class_name()`